# Unable to attach SQL Server database with shared folder in docker on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017, docker, vmware

The problem I'm having is that my SQL Server 2017 Linux container is not able to read my database files. I guess it has something to do with permissions and I'm sure I've overlooked something but I can't fugure it out.

I have created a clone with the PowerShell module called dbaclone.
This module creates and attaches a differencing disk based on another VHD making it easier to provision large databases.

The databases are available using a partition access path which will look something like this

[image]

With in the folder, in example "AW2017-C1" is a folder called "Data" and "Log" containing the data and the log files respectively.

The permissions on the folder are "Everyone" to have "Full Control".

[image]

I have a virtual machine in VMWare Workstation which is a Linux VM. The Linux VM has Docker installed. I shared the clone folder in the VM

[image]

To make it easier to use I added the share to /etc/fstab to mount it automatically when the VM starts.

[image]

The permissions are all set that everyone should be able to read it

[image]

I have the following script to run the docker container

```
sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' \
    -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Myp@ssw0rd' \
    -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 \
    -v /home/sander/databases:/databases \
    -v /home/sander/shares/dbaclone:/var/opt/mssql/data/dbaclone \
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

The docker container will mount the directory and make it accessible for the container.

The file permissions from within the container look correct

[image]

Everything looks ok, but when i run the following script

```
USE master;

CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2017
ON PRIMARY
       (
           FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/dbaclone/AW2017-C1/Data/AdventureWorks2017.mdf'
       ),
       (
           FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/dbaclone/AW2017-C1/Log/AdventureWorks2017_log.ldf'
       )
FOR ATTACH;
```

This error comes back

> Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 3
>   Unable to open the physical file "/var/opt/mssql/data/dbaclone/AW2017-C1/Data/AdventureWorks2017.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 7, Line 3
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
>   Completion time: 2020-02-19T13:07:36.1675676+01:00

This obviously has something to do with permissions but it all looks good and maybe someone has else has some pointers how to get this fixed.

Comment: I see it is owned by root vs mssql user `chown -R mssql:mssql /var/opt/mssql/`  Follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @KinShah I have tried that but it won't work because this is SQL Server 2017 in Linux which runs as root. Only from SQL Server 2019 it's running under mssql

Comment: any reason u are using 2017 running as root vs 2019 running as non root ? the prior is a security risk and old version.

Comment: @KinShah The main reason is that not a lot of people have migrated to SQL Server 2019 yet. Also, this should never be a production scenario what I'm trying to accomplish.

I also tried to run it with SQL Server 2019, and with the correct access for mssql, and I got the same error. So if I can get this to work with SQL Server 2017 I can probably apply the same resolution to SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem with shares.

One thing I did was remove the share in VMWare because for some reason, the mount with `vmhgfs` did not work well with SQL Server. It just could not get the right privileges even if I tried setting them with chmod.

Instead I installed `CIFS` and mounted the share as

```
sudo mount.cifs //10.100.1.1/dbaclone/clone /data/dbaclone -o credentials=/home/sander/.dbaclonecredentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

This mounted the share as needed.

SQL Server was able to connect to it without any permissions issues.

Comment: Thank you for your research!